# JPA Multiple converters named ... defined in this persistence unit

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

I just checked out the code from my new company. 
They wrote many `@converter` annotation with same names.
(`org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Converter`)
So I have 72 jpa errors: Multiple converters named "`localDateConverter`" defined in this persistence unit

It seems to work for them so I won't change everything.

What jpa validation must I put from error to warning to make it work?

(I looked everywhere and didn't find any looking like this error)

Answer (score 1):

It was in preferences/Java Persistence/JPA/EclipseLink/attribute/Duplicate converter name